# What is the easy way to get the position of a specific video in a video/list?

Tags: jwplayer

For instance, I have a video key and a list of videos returned from JW-Platform API method [video/list](http://apidocs.jwplayer.com/methods/videos/list.html).
The list has 10000 videos and the video with that video key is at Array position 421 from the returned response of the API method video/list.

Do I have to make the BIG call of video/list everytime, loop through video items in the list, and compare one by one if the video key is the same as that item's key, just to get the video position ? Or are there easier and less-overload ways to do so?

Comment: Good question. I am going to ask internally here and get back to you.

Comment: Do you mean the position in a specific video, like how far someone has watched, or do you mean position of a specific video in the playlist?

Comment: Use Case: I want to redirect from a single video page to the video list page, but since my video list page is with paginations. For usability, I want to make sure the redirected list page contains that single video. That's why I need the position of single video from the returned response of the API method video/list

Comment: There isn't really a position as part of that method. Either of the ways you suggested above, while not the prettiest solutions, are probably the only way to be able to get this from video/list.